# xrandr --addmode fails with X Error of failed request: BadMatch

Tags: x11, nvidia, xrandr, monitors

I can run this two commands correctly

```
cvt 3840x2160 70
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_70.00"  839.00  3840 4160 4584 5328  2160 2163 2168 2250 -hsync +vsync
```

But then when I try to add the mode to my device with

```
xrandr --addmode DP-4 "3840x2160_70.00"
```

It fails with the error

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
```

At this point arch wiki basically suggest me to ditch privative drivers and use nouveau. Any idea about how to debug this error? Thank you.